# Spring Batch which configuration is going to run?

Tags: spring-batch

In my simple Spring Batch application, I have a configuration...

```
@Configuration
public class StepTransitionConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public Job transitionJobSimpleNext() {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("transitionJobNext")
                    .start(step1())
                    .next(step2())
                    .build();
    }
```

The only other class is

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class TransitionsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransitionsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So I started thinking how does that Application class know to use that particular configuration for the Batch.  So I added another Configuration...

```
@Configuration
public class AnotherTransitionConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


    @Bean
    public Step step4() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step5() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public Job transitionJobSimpleNext() {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("transitionJobNext")
                    .start(step4())
                    .next(step5())
                    .build();
    }
```

Now when I run the application, it always uses the second configuration even though both are on the classpath.  Why is this?

Comment: Your Job `@Beans` have the same bean name (bean names declared in `@Configuration` files default to the name of the method they are defined in).  When this happens, the second job overwrites the first in the ApplicationContext and thus you always get the second job.  Try changing the name of the second job and they should both run.

Comment: @JoeChiavaroli thanks I'll accept that as an answer.  All I had to do was rename transitionJobSimpleNext to something else in the second config.  Thanks a mill.